# pgfplotstable: Problem with 'create on use', getprevrow (Table similar to "Horner's scheme")

Tags: pgfplotstable

I wrote the explaining text into the image, I hope it is easier to explain in this way:

[image]

Picture without stuff:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
fixed, 1000 sep={\,},
}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Divisor}{857}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Base}{10}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Exponent}{20}
% Text commands
\newcommand\SignForEmptyMultiplierShow{/}


\section{My modulo}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\BinExponent}{bin(\Exponent)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\DimOfBinExponent}{dim(\BinExponent)}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Binarydigits}{\DimOfBinExponent-1}


\colorbox{pink}{Example (!): $10^{\Exponent} \bmod \Divisor = \,?$} \par
Binary representation of the exponent:  $%~\big\vert
 \Exponent=\colorbox{cyan}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\BinExponent}}_{\,(2)}
% ,~~\dim(\BinExponent_{(2)}) = \DimOfBinExponent
$ (we can find these numbers again in the column "Occupation".)

\section{pgfplotstable try}
\pgfplotstableset{create on use/Binarydigit/.style={
create col/set list={\Binarydigits,...,0}},
columns/my new col/.style={string type}}

\pgfplotstableset{create on use/Occupation/.style={
create col/assign/.code={
\getthisrow{Binarydigit}\BinarydigitNo
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Binarydigit}{array({\BinExponent},\Binarydigits-\BinarydigitNo)}%
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\Binarydigit}}}

\pgfplotstableset{create on use/MultiplierShow/.style={
create col/assign/.code={
\getthisrow{Occupation}\occupier
\pgfmathsetmacro{\multiplier}{\occupier==1 ? "$\cdot \Base$" : "\SignForEmptyMultiplierShow"}%
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\multiplier}}}


\pgfplotstableset{create on use/MultiplierIs/.style={
create col/assign/.code={
\getthisrow{Occupation}\occupier
\pgfmathsetmacro{\multiplier}{\occupier==1 ? \Base : 1}%
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\multiplier}}}

\pgfplotstableset{create on use/Results/.style={
create col/assign/.code={
\getthisrow{Binarydigit}\BinarydigitNo
\getthisrow{Occupation}\occupier
\getthisrow{MultiplierIs}\multiplierX
\getthisrow{ModI}\modI
\pgfmathsetmacro{\results}{\BinarydigitNo==\Binarydigits ? \occupier*\Base : 1}%
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\results}}}

\pgfplotstableset{create on use/ModI/.style={
create col/assign/.code={
\getthisrow{Binarydigit}\BinarydigitNo
\getthisrow{Occupation}\occupier
\getthisrow{Results}\results
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ModI}{\BinarydigitNo==\Binarydigits ? mod(\results,\Divisor) : 1}%
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\ModI}}}


\pgfplotstableset{create on use/Square/.style={
create col/assign/.code={
\getthisrow{Binarydigit}\BinarydigitNo
\getthisrow{Occupation}\occupier
\getthisrow{Results}\results
\getthisrow{ModI}\modI
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Square}{\BinarydigitNo==\Binarydigits ? \modI*\modI : 1}%
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\Square}}}

\pgfplotstableset{create on use/ModII/.style={
create col/assign/.code={
\getthisrow{Binarydigit}\BinarydigitNo
\getthisrow{Occupation}\occupier
\getthisrow{Results}\results
\getthisrow{Square}\square
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ModI}{\BinarydigitNo==\Binarydigits ? mod(\square,\Divisor) : 1}%
\pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\ModI}}}




\pgfplotstablenew[columns={Binarydigit, Occupation, MultiplierShow, MultiplierIs, Results, ModI, Square, ModII}]{\DimOfBinExponent}\modulotable

\noindent\pgfplotstabletypeset[%string type, 
columns={Binarydigit, Occupation, MultiplierShow, MultiplierIs, Results, ModI, Square, ModII},
1000 sep={\,}, 
columns/Binarydigit/.style={column name=Binarydigit},
columns/Occupation/.style={column name=Occupation},
columns/MultiplierShow/.style={string type, column name=MultiplierShow},
columns/ModI/.style={column name=$\bmod\, \Divisor$},
columns/Square/.style={column name=Square},
columns/ModII/.style={column name=$\bmod\, \Divisor$},
]{\modulotable}

\section{This is what it should be}
\newcommand\R{\cellcolor{red}}
\newcommand\g{\cellcolor{green}}
\newcommand\G{\cellcolor{green!50!black}}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }
Binarydigit & Occupation & Multiplier & Results & mod 857 & Square & mod 857  \\  
4 & 1 & $\cdot$10 & 10         & 10        & 100       & \g 100  \\
3 & 0 & /               &  \G 100 &  \G 100 & 10000    & \g 573  \\
2 & 1 & $\cdot$10 &   5730   &   588     & 345744  & \g 373  \\
1 & 0 & /               & \G  373 & \G  373 &  139129  &   295  \\
0 & 0 & /               & \R 295  & \R 295  & \R 87025 & \R 468  \\
%1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7  \\
\end{tabular}
\colorbox{pink}{$\Rightarrow 10^{20} \bmod{857} = 295$}

\begin{itemize}
\item The dark green cells does not need to be shown, so let them empty - same content in green cells!  {\color{red} How to get these previous cells for the "Square"-column  with pgfplots?}

\item The red part has to be completely  empty - a bigger modulo (468) than the previous (295) {\color{red}[I think\dots]}.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your command `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Square}{\occupier==0 ? "test" : \Squareing}%` sets `\Square` to `"test"` if `\occupier==0`. In the two rows in which Occupation is 0 you get `test`. To me this seems all consistent. `\getprevrow{ModII}\test` does not even get used as far as I can see. What precisely do you want to achieve?

Comment: I feel that there is a misunderstanding what `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Binarydigit}{array({\BinExponent},\Binarydigits-\BinarydigitNo)}%` does. What do you want to achieve here? `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` applied to an array does not convert the entries of the array to integers. Maybe you want `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Binarydigit}{min(int(\BinExponent),int(\Binarydigits-\BinarydigitNo))}` here, at least it yields a more reasonable output.

Comment: Puh, I think, I have some thinking mistakes. I will try to fix. For the background (but, I fear this is only for german readers): I want to teX the section *„Modulo“ statt „Rest bei Division“* from https://www.arndt-bruenner.de/mathe/scripts/periodenlaenge.htm

Comment: Could you perhaps explain in simple terms what you want to achieve. While I think to understand the link, I do not know what the binaries have to do with it. (Possibly I was reading the wrong link.) Nor the role of `array`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I edited the task completely. Thanks for your interessts.

Comment: "Interests" means "Zinsen" ;-)

Comment: Ouh, so while you don't pay me some interests, thanks for your attentions.

Comment: I still do not understand the question but one issue might be that the results of the later columns do not seem to be available. If you add `\typeout{\BinarydigitNo,\Binarydigits,\occupier,\Base,\modI->\results}%` to `create on use/Results/.style={...` then you see that it does not yet know `\modI`, probably because it is in a column that is right of `Results`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Yes, I think so too. What could be a possible way, to fix that?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from doing all the computation in one column, or reorder the columns.

Comment: By doing all the computations in one column, I do not know how to get the results. Maybe I can add some invisible columns...

Comment: I think it could be much easier to create this table by rows (not bei cols). But it seem, there is no way, as you told me in another question.

Comment: I definitely did not say that in the other answer, at least I did not mean to say anything like this. However, your previous question could be very easily answered in the way I did. I have not really read the linked post, but if you have formulae that compute the output from some data then it will be straightforward to  build them into some table.

Comment: Ohh, the way, where the numbers (in  "section 3") come from, is not clear?

Comment: Yes. Do you have simple formulae?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat If I edit some "nice" arrows, can you imagine the computation? I fear it is not the simpliest algorithm ever... ;)