# pgfplotstable: Create rows with loops

Tags: pgfplotstable

Is it possible to create rows with loops?

I thought about something like that:

```
\○pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5}{%
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
#1 & #1 & #1 
}\temp
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\main}{\temp}
}%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\main}
```

But this does not work. What have I to do?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape=false]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
% Start
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
999 & 999 & 999
}\main

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
1 & 1 & 1  
}\temp

Works:
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\main}{\temp}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\main}

Works not:
%\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5}{%
%\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&]{
%#1 & #1 & #1 
%}\temp
%\pgfplotstablevertcat{\main}{\temp}
%}%
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[]{\main}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your main problem is that `\pgfplotstableread` just reads data, it does not expand macros etc {the column are row separators are probably not so much expanded as searched for).

Comment: Mmh, I do not know, how to fix that.

Comment: It might be easier to add one column at a time using `[create col/set list={\macro}]`. where `\macro` is created in a loop.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Mhh, creating by columns, I have tried here (and that is the main problem):   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518684/pgfplotstable-problem-with-create-on-use-getprevrow-table-similar-to-horne    this was not much easier / successfuller :()

Comment: Puh, an idea could be to ship out needed rows into a text-file and bring them back as main-table. But I hope, there is an easier way...

Comment: I tried looking at the internal format of table using \show and the source code.  The header is fairly straight forward, but can't find the data.